# How to seperate multiple numbers in one cell and count correct numbers?

Tags: r

I have a table with IDs and ANSWERS that are saved in one cell and separated by a comma. Test scores are stored as character.

| ID | ANSWERS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2, 4, 8 |
| 2 | 2, 8 |
| 3 | 4, 8 |
| 4 |  |

I want to create a column that gives one point to each correct answer (2 is correct, 4 is correct, and 8 is correct). This would lead to a final result:

| ID | SCORE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 |

Do you have any idea how I can do this? The problem is that numbers are saved as character and are in one cell. I tried strsplit, unlist, as.numeric but nothing worked. Further I don't know how to calculate the SCORE. Maybe with some if clause. Thank you so much for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: Try

    correctAnswers<-c(2,4,8)

    df$SCORE<-unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$ANSWERS, split = ","), function(x, corA){sum(!is.na(match(x, correctAnswers)))}, corA=correctAnswers))

Comment: @AStieb you made my day! Thank you so much, everything worked!